# neo4j 3 "thirdparty_jaxrs_classes" config

Tags: neo4j

I am testing neo4j 3 before upgrading the production, and it seems that this key doesn't bind an http endpoint anymore: (added to neo4j.conf)

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it has been changed to :

`dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes`

Example :

`dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware`

Concerning upgrades, a few links :

General upgrade announcement : http://neo4j.com/guides/upgrade/

Neo4j changelog : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.0-changelog

Upgrade instructions and config migrator tool : http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/#upgrade-instructions

Comment: I wish i could find a full list of changes from 2.x to 3.1